# jquery easyui dynamically created tabs to refresh contained iframe everytime the icon-class is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I have the following tree building tabs dynamically. The tabs are having an iframe which source is taken from a json file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){   
   $('#tree_menu').tree({    
   animate:true,    
    onClick: function open1(node){
      if ($('#tabs').tabs('exists',node.id)){
      $('#tabs').tabs('select', node.id); 
       } else {
        $('#tabs').tabs('add',{
        title: node.id,
        content: "<iframe id='superframe' frameborder='0' width='100%' scrolling='auto' height='99%' src='" + node.attributes.url + "'><iframe>",
        closable:true, 
        tools:[{  
         iconCls:'icon-mini-refresh',  
         handler:function(){  
           alert('refreshing'); 
        $('#superframe').get(0).contentWindow.location.reload();    
         }  
        }] 

        });
      }
    }
  });

  $('#tabs').tabs({
  onBeforeClose: function(title){
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to close ' + title);
    }
  });

});
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is on the tab icon-mini-refresh is clicked, to reload the iframe in that specific tab. 
With my above code, I'm able to do this, but it works just for the first opened tab. Starting with the second it is not working anymore. It is just not refreshing....
I've tried all the possible iframe reload methods found on google, but without any success.

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried also using jquery, and rewriting the src: `code` $('#superframe').attr('src', node.attributes.url);

The same problem appears. I open the first tab, click refresh icon, everything is ok, the iframe refreshes, but when the second tab is opened, the refresh will not work. The third the same, and so on.

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Id of iframe should be unique to achieve this, please try the below code,

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){   
   $('#tree_menu').tree({    
   animate:true,    
    onClick: function open1(node){
      if ($('#tabs').tabs('exists',node.id)){
      $('#tabs').tabs('select', node.id); 
       } else {
        var frameId='superframe'+node.id;
        $('#tabs').tabs('add',{
        title: node.id,
        content: "<iframe id='"+frameId+"' frameborder='0' width='100%' scrolling='auto'     height='99%' src='" + node.attributes.url + "'><iframe>",
        closable:true, 
        tools:[{  
         iconCls:'icon-mini-refresh',  
         handler:function(){  
           alert('refreshing'); 
        $('#'+frameId).get(0).contentWindow.location.reload();    
         }  
        }] 

        });
      }
    }
  });

  $('#tabs').tabs({
  onBeforeClose: function(title){
   return confirm('Are you sure you want to close ' + title);
   }
 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Saigitha! It works just great.
Didn't realized it needs an unique frame id.

Thank you again.

Comment: Appeared a small problem now. The tabs are containing some pages which contains some links (cgi-script). The refresh is working ok when loading the first content, but when clicking the link from the loaded page, content generated by the cgi-bin script in the iframe is not reloaded. Any idea why?